# Value of next element is entered in current element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to enter the "Password" element using Python (Selenium). The first element entered is User ID, next is Password element.

The problem is when i enter the "Password" after entered the User ID, the value for User ID has no problem. But, when value of Password is entered, it is entered in User ID field.

Eg:

User ID: Ain
Password: abc

System enter the password in User ID field.So, it will be shown like this,

- User ID: Ainabc
- Password: (blank)

Code trials:

```
filepath = "C:/Users/siti11074/Payroll Master/login_test.xlsx"#Config file
wb = load_workbook(filepath)
config_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Config')

b2=config_sheet['C3']
user_id = b2.value
b3=config_sheet ['C4']
password = b3.value

driver.find_element_by_id("USERID_I").send_keys(user_id)
time.sleep(2.0)
print("User ID is entered")

elem_pwd=driver.find_element_by_id("USERPWD_I")
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem_pwd).send_keys(password).perform()
time.sleep(2.0)
print("Password is entered")
```

Expected Result:

- System need to enter the User ID value in User ID field.
- And for Password value in Password field.

Comment: Is the website accessible for public for troubleshooting? Try to do click action before send_keys(password)

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML